# Determine Which Objects Reference a Table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, relationship, table-rename

I need to rename a table that has many columns and stored procedures that process against that table. How can one get all Items in database that have a relation to a table in such a scenario?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you need to find database objects (e.g. tables, columns, triggers) by name - have a look at the **FREE** Red-Gate tool called [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) which does this - it searches your entire database for any kind of string(s).

[image]

[image]

It's a great must-have tool for any DBA or database developer - did I already mention it's absolutely **FREE** to use for any kind of use??

Answer (score 62):

Using [`sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630351.aspx):

```
SELECT 
    referencing_schema_name, referencing_entity_name, referencing_id, 
    referencing_class_desc, is_caller_dependent
FROM 
    sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('mySchemaName.myTableName', 'OBJECT');
GO
```

where `'mySchemaName.myTableName'` is your schema.table,  for example  `'dbo.MyTable'`

Comment: Thanks.But what is "mySchemaName" and "OBJECT"?

Comment: @Tavousi - See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630351.aspx As you can see you want to use `'OBJECT'` as the second parameter. The default schema in SQL Server is `dbo` so that's probably your schema.

Comment: If this unexpectedly returns 0 rows for you, be aware that in SQL Server 2008-2012, sys.dm_sql_referencing_entites requires CONTROL permission on the referenced object to work. Try running the query as a database user with elevated permisisons.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for finding objects referenced in a different database to the one where the SP is being executed

Comment: I tried this on an ancient SQL 2008 (10.0) box, searching for a table and it returned two views but not the four triggers defined on the table.  Should it have returned them?

Answer (score 0):

if you want of ref of DB item like table, column, procedure, etc..

You can use [visual-expert](https://www.visual-expert.com/) tools, we can analyse the code SqlServer code

more info: https://www.visual-expert.com/EN/visual-expert-documentation/code-cross-references/